# Replace null values in a dataframe using another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

I'm trying to replace null values in dataframe `d` using dataframe `f`.

`d` and `f` are linked by `EGI`. In `d`, `EGI` is a column and is not unique. In `f`, `EGI` is unique and is this dataframe's index.

For each row in `d`, I need the values in that row to be 'masked' by the row in `f` with corresponding `EGI`.

Sample data:

```py
d = pd.DataFrame({'EGI':['a1','b2','a1','d4'],'A': ['x', np.nan, 'z', 'e'], 'B': [pd.NaT, 6, 7, 9], 'C': [2, 1, None, 9], 'D': [2, None, np.nan, None]})

  EGI    A    B    C    D
0  a1    x  NaT  2.0  2.0
1  b2  NaN    6  1.0  NaN
2  a1    z    7  NaN  NaN
3  d4    e    9  9.0  NaN
```

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'B': [5, 8, 9], 'A': ['w', 'y', np.nan], 'D': [None, np.nan, 8], 'test': [5, 8, 9]}, index=['b2', 'a1', 'c3'])

    B    A    D  test
b2  5    w  NaN     5
a1  8    y  NaN     8
c3  9  NaN  8.0     9
```

Expected output:

```
  EGI    A    B    C    D
0  a1    x    8  2.0  2.0
1  b2    w    6  1.0  NaN
2  a1    z    7  NaN  NaN
3  d4    e    9  9.0  NaN
```

What I tried:

```
m = d.isnull()
m.index = d['EGI'].tolist()
m = m.drop(['EGI'], axis = 1)
d.mask(m, f)

   EGI    A    B   C   D
0  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: one easiest approach is, Merge Two dataframes and fill nan of left cols to right cols then remove right cols.

Answer (score 2):

If dataframes `d` and `f` have matching row indexes, we can just [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
d.fillna(f)
```

But in OP's example, the indexes do not match up, so we just need to align them first.

---

#### One-liner

Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to align the indexes to `EGI` and then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
d.set_index('EGI').fillna(f.reindex(d.EGI))

#    EGI  A    B    C    D
# 0   a1  x  8.0  2.0  2.0
# 1   b2  w    6  1.0  NaN
# 2   a1  z    7  NaN  NaN
# 3   d4  e    9  9.0  NaN
```

---

#### Step-by-step

1. Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to set `d`'s index to `EGI`:

   ```
   d = d.set_index('EGI')

   #        A    B    C    D
   # EGI                    
   # a1     x  NaT  2.0  2.0
   # b2   NaN    6  1.0  NaN
   # a1     z    7  NaN  NaN
   # d4     e    9  9.0  NaN
   ```
2. Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to align `f`'s index to `d`'s index:

   ```
   f = f.reindex(d.index)

   #        B    A   D  test
   # EGI                    
   # a1   8.0    y NaN   8.0
   # b2   5.0    w NaN   5.0
   # a1   8.0    y NaN   8.0
   # d4   NaN  NaN NaN   NaN
   ```
3. Use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill `d`'s NaNs with `f`:

   ```
   d.fillna(f)

   #    EGI  A    B    C    D
   # 0   a1  x  8.0  2.0  2.0
   # 1   b2  w    6  1.0  NaN
   # 2   a1  z    7  NaN  NaN
   # 3   d4  e    9  9.0  NaN
   ```

Note that the *column* indexes of `d` and `f` are not aligned and do not need to be. We only need to align the *row* indexes, and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) will handle the rest.